# Why i can't see custom created icomoon icons in my app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

i have created 4 icons in icomoon, get the `ttf` and `selection.js` file, put them on the project, linked the vector-icons properly, get the `ttf` file in `info.plist` file BUT i can't see them on my app! However, there is a blank space where the icon should be, when i click it(they are `TouchableOpacity` btw) they are working as expected, except the visuals.

Here is how i get icons:

```
import {createIconSetFromIcoMoon} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import icoMoonConfig from '../assets/fonts/selection.json';
export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(icoMoonConfig,'icomoon', 'icomoon.ttf');
```

This is how i use it in my app:

```
 <CustomIcon
   name={'timer'}
   size={25} 
   style={{color: colors.BUTTON_BCK}}
 />
```

Comment: it is really sad that no one answer this :(

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who come here here is the solution: if your svg quality is not good, icomoon will not convert it properly. so make sure you have pixel perfect svg files before converting them to ttf.

Answer (score -1):

I use fontello for this instead of icomoon. I should add my font to

1. resource folder
2. info.plist
3. in xcode -> target -> build phases -> copy bundle resources

then run `react-native link` and build it again. it should work.